# How can I get current GPS location in every n seconds when app is not running in background (suspended) for ios10 even if user covers 50 meters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location, ios10

I'm creating location based mobile app using sample project given at: https://github.com/voyage11/Location. I'm saving the received locations in local database and showing locations on map when app comes in foreground.
Problem is- when device is connected with power, app works and the moment I remove the device from charging no more locations updates are received(my app is not working when it is suspended from background).

Comment: You cannot do hat. You will have to move something around 500m to receive a location update in background.

Comment: @Hermann Klecker, I'm newbie in ios. Would you please explain why does it happen or any reference link.Thank you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html
Scroll a bit down to "Tracking the User’s Location"

Comment: This is a tutorial related to all background modes available: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: We've tried this extensively in my last project. We did not manage to being called in background more often than when the location changed significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.
The best you can use is startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method, it can get locations when the app is in background or not.
Here's the docs :
https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get continuous location updates from the background is to register your app as a navigation app. That will allow you to keep monitoring the user's location continously, but note that the GPS uses a lot of power and you will drain the user's battery quite quickly.

As @GhazyDENDEN says in their answer, you **could** use the significant location changes API, but that will only give you updates when the phone moves by a significant distance (see the docs for details) and if the phone is stationary you won't get ANY updates.

Also, when you go to submit your app to the app store Apple may decide that it does not qualify as a navigation app and they may reject it. I suggest resolving that question early in the development process so you don't waste a lot of development time and then get rejected.